# How to calculate the corner points of a grid if centre points are know

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf, wgs84, pyproj

I am working with a file which has the coordinates in WGS84 format. From this file I have calculated the Cartesian coordinates using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyproj
from netCDF4 import Dataset
_projections = {}


def unproject(z, l, x, y):
    if z not in _projections:
        _projections[z] = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=z, ellps='WGS84')
    if l < 'N':
        y -= 10000000
    lng, lat = _projections[z](x, y, inverse=True)
    return (lng, lat)

def calculate_grid_definition(in_path):
    """
    Calculate the latitude and longitude coordinates of the cell.

    :param in_path: Path to the file that contains all the information.
    :type in_path: str

    :return: Latitudes array, Longitudes array, Latitude interval, Longitude interval.
    :rtype: numpy.array, numpy.array, float, float
    """
    with Dataset(in_path) as f:
        utm_lat = f.variables['LAT'][:]
        utm_lon = f.variables['LON'][:]
        geolat = np.zeros((len(utm_lon), len(utm_lat)))
        geolon = np.zeros((len(utm_lon), len(utm_lat)))
        for x, u_lon in enumerate(utm_lon):
            for y, u_lat in enumerate(utm_lat):
                lon_now, lat_now = unproject(32, 'N', u_lon, u_lat)
                geolat[x, y] = lat_now
                geolon[x, y] = lon_now

        return geolat, geolon

inpfile = 'path/to/filename.nc'
geolat, geolon = calculate_grid_definition(inpfile)
```

Now I also want to calculate the corner points of the grid cells. Assuming a regular rectangular grid, it would be very simple with the following code:

```
def create_bounds(coordinates):
    interval_x = coordinates[1, :] - coordinates[0, :]
    interval_y = coordinates[:, 1] - coordinates[:, 0]
    interval_x = np.tile(interval_x, (len(interval_y), 1))
    interval_y = np.tile(interval_y, (interval_x.shape[-1], 1)).T

    coords_left = coordinates - interval_x / 2
    coords_right = coordinates + interval_x / 2
    coords_bottom = coordinates - interval_y / 2
    coords_top = coordinates + interval_y / 2

    bound_coords = np.dstack((coords_left, coords_top,
                              coords_right, coords_bottom))
    return bound_coords


lat_bnds = create_bounds(geolat)
lon_bnds = create_bounds(geolon)
```

But, this is not right because the grids are skewed and result in an overlap. Any leads?
For your information, you could download the original grid coordinates from this [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15tVtRh8Q-_qGaPpwnNbfEaSaL6opLfaB). An alternative download link is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgvMFbyJOEXTnjyvKqvSDeQPs6kd).

Comment: `Access denied` to file content :-(

Comment: Don't know why, but I have added an alternative download link from Onedrive

Answer (score 1):

Are the original .nc coordinates in long/lat or grid coordinates? I ask, as it says `LAT` and `LONG`, rather than `North` and `East`. I guess they are UTM North and East coordinates in Zone 32 N, ie EPSG:32632.

If your original data are on a rectangular grid, then your unprojected data will not be.

Your function `create_bounds` makes boxes around the original UTM pixel centres after backprojection to geodetic coordinates.

Your interval_x etc computation uses specific rows of coordinates, but we know that the **grid interval is not constant** in geodetic coordinates. So you may be getting overlapping or disjoint polygons. Instead, maybe something like this would respect each individual grid element spacing:

```
dx = coordinates[1:,:] - coordinates[:-1,:]
dy = coordinates[:,1:] - coordinates[:,:-1]
```

Then the inter-row and -column differences would be retained. You could then compute the bounds of each cell from these.

Note that dx and dy outlined above will have M-1 X N-1 points, whereas you want M+1 X N+1 points to create bounds over all pixels. Just copy the edge values to one more row or column at each edge.

I looked at scipy.interpolate, but I couldn't see a quick way to generate midpoints and add edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You guessed it right, the names in the original files are wrong. These are north and east. Probably I could not convey what I want at the end. What you suggested provides the corner points f my entire data. What I actually want is corner points of the individual grids. For example, after transformation, geolat and geolon are array of dimension 642x873. The corner points should be array of shape 642x873x4.